# Is it possible to load interactive elements into an iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Does anyone have any ideas how I could package an external interactive slide that could be dynamically loaded by an iOS app? Is it at all possible?

e.g. Imagine having a presentation app on an iPad. There is a set of interactive slides held on the web somewhere, let's say they contain draggable elements.

Can I load one of these slide objects into the app and interact with it? If so, what format would the slide object be?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's possible to dynamically load bundles ([NSBundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Concepts/CFNSBundle.html)) components in an app. These bundles could even contain executable code, though AppStore guidelines prohibit use of dynamically loaded NSBundles in this way for security reasons.

Additionally you could just use a UIWebView to display some 'slides' on a webpage, though it will be very hard to make the app behave as if it's the same as the native slides - perhaps even impossible (due to how rendering of webpages work compared to native controls, for example).

Comment: I really don't see how NSBundle becomes relevant here, and even less AppStore guidelines. A 'slide' would just be data, and you can load data from the web into your app, or include it in your app, and Apple would never complain about it as long as there is nothing fishy going on. An 'interactive' slide does not mean it has to have executable code. If your app is a 'reader'/'editor' kind of app and it handles slideshows it doesn't matter if the slide contains objects that the user could interact with. Compare it with a drawsomething-drawing, a canvas or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so lets say you have these "external interactive slides" on a web server somehow. Since you are not saying they are of a certain type (like powerpoint or such) I will just assume that these slides are of some rare format that is probably not supported by any existing apps or the Safari browser.

Then the answer to your question would be: Write your own iOS-app that can read, present and edit these slides. What format are they? Well it doesn't matter. Write an app that can download the slide data from the data and parse it, and present it on the phone.

Then let the user interact with it, and perhaps make the app upload the changes to the server.

You can do anything you like in your app, there are no limits. You just have to write the code for it. If there was some kind of standardised format, lets say you wanted your app to show powerpoint presentations, then you would have 3 choices. Use someone else´s app, or write your own app with a parser for the powerpoint files or make your own app that use some code that someone else wrote to do it (a third part library that you include in your app)

In your specific case, I can not tell if there are any third part librarys to interact with your slides, but my guess is that you will need to do most of it on your own. You could start with looking at how the web services that interact with the slides online works, and if you can interact with them from an iOS-app that you make yourself.

There is nothing stopping you from creating an app, read the slide data into the app, present it in any way you like, let the user change it, save it in your app, or upload the changes to a server. It's all up to you =)

Good luck!